# Terminal curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused

Tags: ruby, node.js, curl, terminal

I am using OSX Elcapitan, 10.11.6, when I run

```
curl localhost:3000
```

or

```
curl localhost:3000 -4
```

or

```
curl 0.0.0.0:3000
```

or

```
curl -x "" "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
```

It always says:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000: Connection refused

```
ruby -v
```

> ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

my code:

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    CollectionDriver = require('./collectionDriver').CollectionDriver;

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

var mongoHost = 'localHost';
var mongoPort = 27017;
var collectionDriver;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo-server';
// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(error, db) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  console.log("Connected to MongoDB successfully.");
  collectionDriver = new CollectionDriver(db);
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>');
});

app.get('/:collection', function(req, res) {
   var params = req.params;
   collectionDriver.findAll(req.params.collection, function(error, objs) {
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
          else {
              if (req.accepts('html')) {
                  res.render('data',{objects: objs, collection: req.params.collection});
              } else {
              res.set('Content-Type','application/json');
                  res.send(200, objs);
              }
         }
    });
});

app.get('/:collection/:entity', function(req, res) {
   var params = req.params;
   var entity = params.entity;
   var collection = params.collection;
   if (entity) {
       collectionDriver.get(collection, entity, function(error, objs) {
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
          else { res.send(200, objs); }
       });
   } else {
      res.send(400, {error: 'bad url', url: req.url});
   }
});

app.post('/:collection', function(req, res) {
    var object = req.body;
    var collection = req.params.collection;
    collectionDriver.save(collection, object, function(err,docs) {
          if (err) { res.send(400, err); }
          else { res.send(201, docs); }
     });
});

app.put('/:collection/:entity', function(req, res) {
    var params = req.params;
    var entity = params.entity;
    var collection = params.collection;
    if (entity) {
       collectionDriver.update(collection, req.body, entity, function(error, objs) {
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
          else { res.send(200, objs); }
       });
   } else {
       var error = { "message" : "Cannot PUT a whole collection" }
       res.send(400, error);
   }
});

app.delete('/:collection/:entity', function(req, res) {
    var params = req.params;
    var entity = params.entity;
    var collection = params.collection;
    if (entity) {
       collectionDriver.delete(collection, entity, function(error, objs) {
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
          else { res.send(200, objs); }
       });
   } else {
       var error = { "message" : "Cannot DELETE a whole collection" }
       res.send(400, error);
   }
});

app.use(function (req,res) {
    res.render('404', {url:req.url});
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: What kind of application do you expect to answer requests on that port? How does your program look like? How did you start your program?

Comment: is the application running on that port.

Comment: Please check my update code above. Thanks.

Comment: Note "0.0.0.0" is *not* localhost...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you didn't start your server, or it's running on a port other than the one you're expecting.

If this is a Rails app, `rails c` gets it going. If it's some other Rack based program you'll need to launch it another way, like with [Pow](http://pow.cx).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I should open another terminal window to do this. Thanks.

Comment: The advantage of another window is you get to watch the logs, and those often reveal a lot about how your application is performing.